# Laravel : Broadcast event with PresenceChannel

Tags: laravel, events, laravel-5.4, broadcast, pusher

I'm trying to broadcast an event in a case where two user share a conversation (like a chat) where only the two of the can access and get notified when a new message comes.

I think, after reading the documentation that the presence channel is the best option (private is for one people and the server and channel is for something plublic without checking ?)

So in my `routes/channels.php` I have something like this:

```
Broadcast::channel('conversation.{conversation}', function ($user, Conversation $conversation) {
    if ($user->id === $conversation->user1_id || $user->id === $conversation->user2_id) {
        return $user;
    }

    return null;
});
```

In the client side a Component I have:

```
Echo
.join('conversation.${conversation.id}')
.here((users) => {
    this.usersInRoom = users;
})
.joining((user) => {
    this.usersInRoom.push(user);
})
.leaving((user) => {
    this.usersInRoom = this.usersInRoom.filter(u => u != user);
})
.listen('MessagePosted', (e) => {
    this.messages.push({
        id :e.message.id,
        user_id :e.message.user_id,
        conversation_id :e.message.conversation_id,
        user :e.user,
        text :e.message.text,
        created_at :e.message.created_at,
        updated_at :e.message.updated_at,
    });
});
```

And the class that emit the even MessagePosted :

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PresenceChannel('conversation.'.$this->message->conversation_id);
}
```

So I now that previously I used a PresenceChannel without any checking, so if two people where in there conversation they would get notification from everyone. not the right thing.

In the server side, I have the `'conversation.{conversation}'` that was mentioned in the documentation to make a separated channel. But I also saw something like `'conversation.*'`.

And on the client side I have `join('conversation.${conversation.id}')` but here I am not sure at all I just know that I have in the props (props : ['user', 'friend', 'conversation']) a conversation which is an object with the id of the conversation.

So When, when everyone was on the same channel with no restriction everything was working perfectly and now, I think I have an error which make the whole thing not work.

I have two 500 server side error when I load a client conversation :

```
ReflectionException in Broadcaster.php line 170:
Class Conversation does not exist
```

(And in the route/channels.php I import the Conversation class `use App\Conversation;`)

and

```
HttpException in Broadcaster.php line 154:
```

Comment: Can you share some of your Broadcaster.php code?

Comment: Huh @chasenyc ? The broadcaster.php file is in the vendor directory so I didn't modify anything in it :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following solution to my problem. I think I saw something in the documentation saying that you might need to use the Path of the class you want to broadcast. So I tried something like this :

In the `routes/channel.php`

```
Broadcast::channel('App.Conversation.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    $conversation = Conversation::findOrFail($id);
    if ($user->id === $conversation->user1_id || $user->id === $conversation->user2_id) {
        return $user;
    }

    return null;
});
```

In the client side in the vue component :

```
Echo
.join('App.Conversation.'+this.conversation.id)
...
```

In the class that emit the event `MessagePosted` :

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PresenceChannel('App.Conversation.'.$this->message->conversation_id);
}
```